# I cannot create a new VPN connection 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, permissions, vpn, system

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 and it seems like I cannot actually create a VPN connectionor manage the network devices.

When I am accessing the network connection using the network icon at the gnome bar I enter the "Edit Connections" -> Add -> PPTP -> Create -> I cannot edit any property of the window.
It states "Editing VPN connection 1" in the top of the windows\form but I cannot edit anything and there for cannot create the VPN connection.

I have also tried to use the "System Settings"-> Network -> "+" button -> interface VPN -> Create -> PPTP -> create -> and again cannot touch any property of the windows.

Maybe it's related to permissions but I don't see any place I can run the "System Settings"-> Network or any other related thing that allows me to elevate my permissions from just "user mode" to a "privileged mode" while I still can run sudo using my password.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the privileges of the user account which will set up the VPN.

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (running in VirtualBox 4.3.20 on 64-bit Windows 7), so the instructions may differ slightly for you if you're using stock Ubuntu.

Find the "Users and Groups" tool in 'Settings'. Click "Advanced Settings" on the right of the dialog (and provide your password when prompted). Check "Connect to wireless and ethernet networks" and then logout and log back in again. (I simply restarted the machine.)

When you log back in, you'll have the ability to add a new VPN using the "Configure VPN..." dialog accessed from Network Manager's toolbar icon.

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered the same problem - dialog was disabled.

**The solution that worked for me was:**

1. Installing network-manager-gnome: `sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome`
2. Starting network-manager: `sudo start network-manager` (In case it is already running might need to stop it and then start again)

After that I tried to create new vpn connection as described and the dialog was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If the VPN configuration tab is greyed out it's because the required plugins are not installed for Gnome NetworkManager. The following plugin should be installed:

**network-manager-pptp** and **network-manager-pptp-gnome** - network management framework PPTP plugin GNOME GUI

To install the above plugin use the apt-get command as follows:

```
$sudo apt-get install network-manager-pptp
```

Now, you can add vpn connection to your system using NetworkManager itself. You may need to restart the NetworkManager as follows:

```
# /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

Hope it could help.

Comment: It is installed already.
I have the option to add the new connection but I cannot change any network related settings.
I cannot even change the LAN ethernet IP settings.
And it's a brand new ubuntu installation.

Comment: I will try to test it later, for now the ubuntu desktop is running in the VM while working on the Windows desktop.