# Cannot create connections through Network Manager - All fields in form are grayed out

Tags: network-manager, xfce, remote-desktop, openvpn, azure

My problem is this: I can't create a new OpenVPN (or any other type) connection using network manager in an Azure Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine. The reason is that once I click *Create*, all options in the editing form appear grayed out (see screenshot) and I can't enter any information in any file of any tab.

[image: Editing VPN connection - All greyed out]

I am login with the default user created during installation, and use a remote desktop connection from windows to access the Ubuntu VM through an Xfce desktop. I've installed the usual OpenVPN packages and network manager plugins (otherwise the OpenVPN option wouldn't even appear).

None of the suggestions in [this similar question worked for me...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520219/i-cannot-create-a-new-vpn-connection-14-04)

I tried changing permissions for "inactive" sessions in  `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy` as hinted by @steeldriver, but still having the same problem.

Also I have noticed a weird thing. Wwhen I logout from my Remote Desktop Xfce session instead of logging out it takes me to a different Xfce session with *two* network manager icons in the top right. If I log out again, it finally logs out and closes the Remote Desktop.

Comment: I think it's normal for NetworkManager actions to be denied to "inactive" (i.e. remote) users by the PolicyKit mechanism - see for example [A brief guide to PolicyKit](http://scarygliders.net/2012/06/20/a-brief-guide-to-policykit/). Does it work if you log in to the XFCE desktop directly on the VM?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @steeldriver. What do you mean by "log in to the XFCE desktop _directly_ on the VM"? My only options are Remote Desktop or VNC, since it's an Azure VM running in the cloud...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on WSL2 and Oracle cloud. Run Network manager with `sudo`

```
sudo nm-connection-editor.
```

Or connect to rdp with `root` username and root password

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar issue. Adding below file solved it.

/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/50-allow-networkmanager.pkla:

```
[Allow NetworkManager username]
Identity=unix-user:username
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.reload;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep-wake;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.scan;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.hostname;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.global-dns;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.checkpoint-rollback;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-statistics;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-connectivity-check
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

Replace *username* (the one in Identity line) with your user name, or * to allow all users interact with NetworkManager (with potential security implications).

Credits: http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12043