# Cannot create vpn connection from Network Manager GUI but using CLI still works 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

everyone!

Why I can create VPN connection only with CLI? I mean, when I run

> sudo openvpn myconfigfile.ovpn

this create vpn connection and everything works fine, but through the Network Manager GUI I don't have any button to create connection at all. They were there but [now they disappeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnRsg.png)
I find out there [I cannot create a new VPN connection 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520219/i-cannot-create-a-new-vpn-connection-14-04) that maybe I should give my user some extra privileges, but I can't find out how I have to do it in 20.04

Please help me, and thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, you do have it. System Settings > Network and inside you'll find "VPN". Click the "+" sign to add a new one, select "openvpn" and proceed.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I did it, but that window, which open when I press "+" sign to add a new vpn connection, have only "Import from file" option, and even if I will try to import vpn connection from file, it returns error message with text "Cannot import vpn connection. The file could not be read or does not contain recognized VPN connection information."

Comment: So it depends on providing the *correct* file. But you're right, I gave instructions applicable to the 21.10 I'm using at this moments. I can't confirm if it should be the same in 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling network manager solved my problem

`sudo apt-get remove network-manager`
`sudo apt-get install network-manage`

Obviously you have to reinstall openvpn plugins also
`sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn`
`sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn-gnome`